What order of Priest was Moses?
Obviously Moses was not of the Aaronic Priesthood. Not only was he not a descendant of Aaron, but in fact he was greater than Aaron. God made him Moses’ prophet (Exodus 7:1-2).
Was Moses of the order of Melchizedek? Or another order perhaps?

You are writing as if you think Moses was, or should have been, a priest? Why do you think that?

Beyond the fact that he functioned as a priest - scripture asserts he was a priest. Psalms 99:6 “Moses and Aaron were among his priests, Samuel was among those who called on his name; they called on the Lord and he answered them.”

are you looking for a biblical basis/commentary or a specific denomination's POV?

related:  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/56545/32868

@depperm as far as I know, this isn’t something that is likely to have much variance between denominations. But yes, scripture + commentary as a basis for the answer would be appreciated :) I’ve asked basically the same question on the Judaism SE as well to see what the traditional answers there might be

Are you looking for biblically based answers or do you accept "additional scriptures" as evidence?

@Lesley I’m fine with an answer based upon extra-biblical sources

This from a response on the Puritan Boards:

The proper way to regard Moses is as the mediator of the Old Covenant. He is completely unique in his role as mediator. He variously combines the offices of judge (king), prophet, and priest. No one would ever do such a thing again until the Christ fulfilled the triple office.

And this from Reconstructing Judaism:

A midrash tells us that during the seven days when Moses was at the burning bush each day he pleaded with God to send someone else (which we know from the Torah text). In the end of the midrash, God informs Moses that because of his unwillingness to take on the task during those seven days he will not be permitted to ascend to the priesthood. Rather, it is Aaron and his descendants who will become the priests. However, for seven days, when the Mishkan is dedicated, Moses will be allowed to perform the priestly functions, but not after that.

It is likely that Moses filled a very unique, transitional role which need not have had precedent (Melchizedek) or descendant (Aaron).  Previous to Levitical Law, temple, and Aaronic Priesthood (in broad brush strokes) God appeared to and spoke directly with individuals (Gen. 12:1, 26:2, for example).
With Moses begins God's speaking to His people (pl) via prophets and the people's access to God via priesthood.  Moses received instruction directly from God in a fashion unlike any other man (save perhaps Abram), face to face, and then He delivered those instructions to the people.

And Jehovah spake unto Moses face to face, as a man speaketh unto his friend. And he turned again into the camp: but his minister Joshua, the son of Nun, a young man, departed not out of the Tent. - Expdus 33:11

Not only Moses but Joshua are in the tent of meeting and Joshua, from Ephraim, is neither a Levite nor a priest of any kind.  The hard separation had not yet begun.  I see Moses not so much as any particular type of priest (although he did perform priestly duties, see especially Leviticus 8) but more as the transition between personal and corporate interaction with God.
God made an unconditional covenant with Abraham and his offspring as an individual.  Through Moses God made conditional covenants with a nation of people.  I suggest the transitional role Moses played between the two is utterly unique and, therefore, unclassified.  Similar in transitional uniqueness to John the Baptist.

I have heard that the/a Jewish position is that Aaron took over the role of High Priest from Moses. I’m curious what the basis for that idea is  After all, Moses continued to intercede for the people - including Aaron - after Aaron and his sons were dedicated. I certainly don’t see a transition of authority to Aaron - in scripture he is always lesser than Moses from what I can tell

THIS IS AN UPDATE TO ADD MORE DETAIL

OP:  Obviously Moses was not of the Aaronic Priesthood.

True enough since the Aaronic Priesthood did not exist until Moses instituted it via washing (baptism) of Aaron.  They were brothers within the Levitical tribe.  This Levitical priesthood was passed down by blood that eventually came to John the Baptist also of the tribe of Levi (Luke 1:5, 13).

And these are the names of the sons of Levi according to their generations; Gershon, and Kohath, and Merari: and the years of the life of Levi were an hundred thirty and seven years. … And the sons of Kohath; Amram, and Izhar, and Hebron, and Uzziel: and the years of the life of Kohath were an hundred thirty and three years. … And Amram took him Jochebed his father's sister to wife; and she bare him Aaron and Moses: and the years of the life of Amram were an hundred and thirty and seven years. Exodus 6:16, 18, 20 (emphasis mine)

Levi, Kohath, Amram, and then brothers Aaron and Moses.

And Moses brought Aaron and his sons, and washed them with water. Lev 8:6

Wash is baptism.  Thus began the Aaronic priesthood of the tribe of Levi.

OP: Or [Moses of] another order perhaps?

Now, to back up in the story before that event that began the Aaronic priesthood, we all recall that Moses was plucked from the Nile and was raised in Pharaoh’s household as one of his own.  Their religion was polytheistic.  The 10 plagues were to show the Egyptians and others the gods they worshipped were false gods.
Moses was raised in that environment; however, his mother would also have an influence about the one true God, though very subtly so as not to raise suspicions.  This sets up what happens after Moses flees Egypt and meets his father-in-law Jethro after marrying Zipporah, Jethro’s daughter.

Now Moses kept the flock of Jethro his father in law, the priest (Kohen) of Midian: and he led the flock to the backside of the desert, and came to the mountain of God, even to Horeb. Exo 3:1

With this, in addition to the Egyptian priesthood, we learn of another priesthood.
Jethro is venerated in a number of religions, but for this story, within the Druze religion.
Unlike the Egyptians who worshipped many gods, the Druze religion is monotheistic.  Jethro had no sons and with his eldest daughter married to Moses, it is reasonable that Moses was also anointed a priest of that religion.  Moses than has the burning bush encounter with the God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob.

OP: Was Moses of the order of Melchizedek?

There is no mention that Moses had a relationship with or even an awareness of the order of Melchizedek.  Moses was of Levi, the priestly tribe.
Indeed, the bible specifically declares this.

For it is evident that our Lord sprang out of Juda; of which tribe Moses spake nothing concerning priesthood.  Heb 7:14

In other words, Moses was of Levi, not Judah, and had no awareness of the Melchizedek priesthood coming out from Judah’s lineage.  He spoke not of it.  Christ was of the seed of David, of the tribe of Judah.
The last bit of information here is after the burning bush, after leaving Egypt, after arriving at Sinai, before the Levitical/Aaronic priesthood, there are unidentified priests with the Israelites (Exo 19:22).
Indeed, the LORD says to them all (priests and non-priests), if you obey all, then you will be a nation of priests.

Now therefore, if ye will obey my voice indeed, and keep my covenant, then ye shall be a peculiar treasure unto me above all people: for all the earth is mine:  And ye shall be unto me a kingdom of priests, and an holy nation. These are the words which thou shalt speak unto the children of Israel. (Exo 19:5-6)

At first the people agreed, but after Sinai and all commandments, after they feared God, they asked for the intermediary (Exo 20:18-19), which became the Aaronic priesthood (Exo 28:1).
So, there are two takeaways.
The first is to recognize that the pattern is about Moses learning about many gods as a priest via Pharoah, then learning about one G/g/od as a priest via Jethro, and lastly, learning about the One True God of Abraham, Isaac, Jacob via the I AM (as translated).
Later, Jethro learned of the I AM and submitted to the LORD.

Now I know that the LORD is greater than all gods: for in the thing wherein they dealt proudly he was above them. Exo 18:11

In this way, all priests of all gods, except Melchizedek, would be submitted to the Aaronic priesthood via Moses.  Incidentally, there's on reference about Moses being a priest to the LORD (Psalm 99:6) via the baptism in the sea.

And were all baptized unto Moses in the cloud and in the sea; 1 Cor 10:2

The second point is this.
A few thousand years later, the John the Baptist "appointed" Christ into the Melchizedek priesthood.  Like Aaron, Jesus did not call Himself into it.

So also Christ glorified not himself to be made an high priest; but he that said unto him, Thou art my Son, to day have I begotten thee. Heb 5:5

Now we know what was meant here.

And Jesus answering said unto him, Suffer it to be so now: for thus it becometh us to fulfil all righteousness. Then he suffered him. Mt 3:15

So, to answer the OP in short, Moses and Aaron were of the Levitical tribe.  Apparently, Moses had been a priest in Egypt to many gods, a priest with Jethro in Median to one god, a priest to the LORD, and then "appointed" via baptism Aaron into the Aaronic priesthood, which essentially “took over” and began the priestly office.
To sum the point, as Moses had subordinated the religions, the gods, the priesthoods to the Aaronic Priesthood Order of the Levitical Tribe under the God of Abraham, Isaac, Jacob, then likewise, some 4,000 years later, tracing that blood lineage from Aaron to John the Baptist, John would further and finally subordinate all religions and priesthoods to Christ Jesus the High Priest of the Melchizedek Priesthood Order.
PS Regarding the transfer of authority of the priesthoods, basically, John the Baptist hints at this with this comment.

He it is, who coming after me is preferred before me, whose shoe's latchet I am not worthy to unloose. John 1:27

The word "preferred" is ginoma Strong's G1096, which may signify a change of condition, state.  Shoe latches refers to the custom of a change of ownership.
PREVIOUSLY POSTED THIS BELOW

OP:  Obviously Moses was not of the Aaronic Priesthood.

Well, the bible says Moses was of the Aaronic tribe.

And there went a man of the house of Levi, and took to wife a daughter of Levi. Ex 2:1

They had a son named Moses who was hid and pulled out from the Nile.
Moses had a brother named Aaron.

And the anger of the LORD was kindled against Moses, and he said, Is not Aaron the Levite thy brother? Ex 4:14


And the LORD said unto Moses, See, I have made thee a god to Pharaoh: and Aaron thy brother shall be thy prophet. Ex 7:1


And Amram took him Jochebed his father's sister to wife; and she bare him Aaron and Moses: and the years of the life of Amram were an hundred and thirty and seven years. Ex 6:20

So, they were both of Levi.

OP: Was Moses of the order of Melchizedek? Or another order perhaps?

Moses was not of the order of Melchizedek.  He was of the Levitical clan.
The point of this narrative is that Moses as prophet "appointed" Aaron into the Aaronic priesthood.  Aaron did not call himself into it.

And Moses brought Aaron and his sons, and washed them with water. Lev 8:6

Wash is baptism.
Likewise, a few thousand years later, the Baptist "appointed" Christ into the Melchizedek priesthood.  Jesus did not call Himself into it.

So also Christ glorified not himself to be made an high priest; but he that said unto him, Thou art my Son, to day have I begotten thee. Heb 5:5

Now we know what was meant here.

And Jesus answering said unto him, Suffer it to be so now: for thus it becometh us to fulfil all righteousness. Then he suffered him. Mt 3:15

So, to answer the OP in short, Moses and Aaron were of the Levitical tribe.  Moses "appointed" via baptism Aaron into the Aaronic priesthood.

Moses was indeed a Levite - but not a descendant of Aaron. If he wasn’t a descendant of Aaron then he can’t have been of the Aaronic Priesthood

Moses and Aaron were brothers (Ex 6:20).  Moses appointed Aaron into the priesthood (Aaronic) that had not existed up until that baptism (wash with water).  Likewise, the Baptist appointed Jesus into the priesthood (Melchizedek whose lineage is unknown).  Most likely we are agreeing on these points.  But simply because Moses did not descend from Aaron (into the Aaronic priesthood) does not mean Moses was of any priesthood, let alone Melchizedek.

See Psalms 99:6. Scripture asserts Moses was a priest

I have some additional information that might help.  I'll be updating my answer later.

TLDR: Yes, Moses had the Melchizedek/Holy Priesthood
I don't know how much overlap there is with other denominations, but the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints has additional scripture and a a specific view point so I'll share their doctrine.
The Melchizedek Priesthood

God first revealed this higher priesthood to Adam. The patriarchs and prophets in every dispensation had this authority (D&C 84:6–17). It was first called the Holy Priesthood, after the Order of the Son of God. It later became known as the Melchizedek Priesthood (D&C 107:2–4).
When the children of Israel failed to live up to the privileges and covenants of the Melchizedek Priesthood, the Lord took away the higher law and gave them a lesser priesthood and a lesser law (D&C 84:23–26). These were called the Aaronic Priesthood and the law of Moses. When Jesus came to the earth, He restored the Melchizedek Priesthood to the Jews and began to build up the Church among them.

The Aaronic Priesthood entry says:

Anciently, under the law of Moses, there were high priests, priests, and Levites. Because the ancient Israelites rebelled against God, Moses and the holy priesthood were taken from them and the lesser priesthood continued.

Moses

Joseph Smith taught that, in company with Elijah, he came to the Mount of Transfiguration and bestowed priesthood keys upon Peter, James, and John (Matt. 17:3–4; Mark 9:4–9; Luke 9:30; D&C 63:21).
...
...he received the priesthood from his father-in-law Jethro (D&C 84:6).

D&C 84:6

6 And the sons of Moses, according to the Holy Priesthood which he received under the hand of his father-in-law, Jethro;

